# What's the radius of convergence of $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\frac{(x-3)^k}{k\cdot 2^k}}$?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

> What's the radius of convergence of
>   $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\frac{(x-3)^k}{k\cdot 2^k}}$?

I figured that the series converges for $1<x<5$. Does that mean that the radius of convergence is $r=5-1=4$?

Comment: For the radius of convergence in general, see Cauchy-Hadamard Radius Formula in wikipedia.

Comment: It is called a radius because if the series converges for all $x\in \Bbb R$ such that $|x-3|<2$ then it converges for all members of $D=\{z\in \Bbb C:|z-3|<2\}$, and $\Bbb C$ can be represented as $\Bbb R^2,$ with $D$ represented as the interior of a circular disc of radius $2$, centered at $(3,0).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a power series around $3$ its radius of convergence is $2$ because it converges for $|x-3|<2$ and diverges for $|x-3| >2$.